# Taking dates into consideration?

Tags: discussion

I often find it that people are referring to this answer or that answer and then say that the topic has already been discussed. Especially in fields like programming, it seems unreasonable though to refer to a topic that was 'solved' 5 years ago, because things develop and although answers in there might not be false, there might be much more effective ways of doing things *now*.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Can you link to examples? If you're referring to situations that happen often then some links would be useful. However, each situation is different. Some 5 year old answers are still perfectly valid solutions now, and still will be in 30 years. It's all about context.

Comment: I agree that some things answered 5 years ago will maybe not be *false*. But  often there are new frameworks or libraries available, or people are discouraging other people from using a particular kind of software/ library / framework because it's buggy, but it might not be buggy *anymore*. I will link to examples if i come across some later. Note that I am talking about computer science in particular, in philosophy things might take more time to change. But you are right nonetheless, it does depend on context and some answer may be perfect still after 5 years.

Comment: I can't see an answerable question here. On what sites does this happen? Enough that the conversation about it needs to happen here rather than on per site metas? Let's say you're right that "people" who claim a topic has "already been discussed" are wrong. OK, what? Where's your question or suggestion? What are you getting at besides "someone is wrong on the internet"? These sites aren't even **for** discussion, they're for Q&A, so "already been discussed" is not actually a response to a question anyway. So, what are you asking?

Comment: am I in the wrong sub? Is this not about suggestions on how to improve stackexchange? I am not asking anything.

Comment: @chrisnolten When you say, *"I often find it that people are referring to this answer or that answer and then say that the topic has already been discussed"* it sounds like you are worried that closing a question as a duplicate of an existing question might not be a good idea if something has changed since the original question.  Is that what you're trying to discuss?

Comment: @AdamDavis yes that's what I mean. I read a question where somebody asked something about programming and the answers were basically that it's very difficult to do. Things like these change relatively fast though, so closing a question that asks this because it is a 'duplicate' does not seem like the right thing to do. Editing the old questions seems valid, but there will be a lot of old information in there which we don't want to delete but it will make the whole thread bigger and less clear. I don't know if people look at questions from years ago and add to that? Does this happen ever?

Comment: i just wanted to put this out there by the way, because it can be annoying at times. maybe somebody will read this and think about it, or somebody will decide that its better the way it is right now. but i wanted to mention it and hear what people think.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to try and revise it into a form that makes what you are asking clearer.

Comment: Please read what I commented above in reply to Kate Gregory. i am not asking anything. my bad.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to approach this issue:

1. Add an answer to the question that updates it with newer solutions
2. Close a question as "too localized" or duplicate of a better question

The first options is generally the best option.  If a newer solution is available, then make a new answer.  Even old questions still get upvotes, and if the question is common/popular, then the better newer solution will rise as long as it's truly better or newer.

The second option is only when the question itself is obsolete.  This is extraordinarily rare, as even very old frameworks are used in existing and new software.  However, it occasionally makes sense to do this if you can find a better representation of the problem and a new way to solve it - closing as a duplicate is usually a better choice.

Keep in mind that there's no **One True Path<sup>TM</sup>** and that an answer that you suppose to be outdated may prove very useful for someone who may be aware of the solution you believe is better, but for their own requirements the "less effective" solution is actually the best to choose.

Since this is a long term repository intended to help many, many people with similar but not exactly the same problem, there's really no problem with having answers that are "outdated" in your eyes.  They are still good answers.

But please do update questions with new answers where you see a possible improvement - the addition of knowledge is welcomed.

But we should be very careful in deleting knowledge.